# IIS Web App performance issues....MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, iis

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  It is running on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  We are noticing significant performance issues when initially loading a page.  We are using nHibernate and have found that performance to be slow in some instances.  But all pages, even simple ones, behavinging similarly.  I'm not really an IIS stud so.....

Am I missing something in IIS....a setting or action that I can tweak to improve performnce?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you creating a SessionFactory every request?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead....no.  Just one on Application_Sart in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: This isn't an IIS thing. I have many NHibernate instances across both shared and dedicated hosting and I never see performance issues as you're describing.

Comment: @Simon....any suggestions on how to investigate nHibernata?

Comment: @Kev.....any suggestions on how to profile the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue running a site on a shared host that only allocated 100MB RAM to an application pool. When you exceeded that IIS was set to recycle it. The app generally ran at about 120MB so was constantly recycling. Each page was loading painfully slow as the whole thing started up again. Increasing the RAM available to the app pool fixed it.

Another thing that I'd try would be to set up SQL profiler and watch the queries being sent to the db. You can configure it to report the duration column in a smaller increment than the default (microseconds perhaps?) which makes the painful ones stand out. You can then pick up ones that are suspect, run them through query analyser with "display execution plan" switched on and examine the subtree costs. Perhaps NHibernate is generating nasty queries or perhaps [too many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)?